# Constructing a nested model by adding one variable at a time

Tags: r

As the question says, I need an automatic procedure that adds one variable at time to the existing linear model E(y) = b0 + b1x + b2x. So one at a time I need to add: `x1x2, x1², x2², x2²*x1,x1²*x2, x1²*x2², x1³, etc.`

At the end of the purpose is to write a function that selects the model with the lowest AIC.
So far, all I can do manually put all models in R like this:

null <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)

```
alt <- lm(y~ x1 +x2 + x1*x2)

alt2 <- lm(y~ x1 +x2 + x1*x2 + I(x1^2))

alt3 <- lm(y~ x1 +x2 + x1*x2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2))

alt4 <- lm(y~ x1 +x2 + x1*x2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2) + I(x1^2)*x2)

alt5 <- lm(y~ x1 +x2 + x1*x2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2) + I(x1^2)*x2 + I(x2^2)*x1)

alt6 <- lm(y~ x1 +x2 + x1*x2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2) + I(x1^2)*x2 + I(x2^2)*x1 + I(x1^3))

alt6 <- lm(y~ x1 +x2 + x1*x2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2) + I(x1^2)*x2 + I(x2^2)*x1 + I(x1^2)*I(x2^2))

...
```

and

so, and then calculate the AIC of these different models.

Is there any automatic way in which a nested model sequence can be generated by adding one variable at time as described above?

Many thanks in advance,

Pieter

Comment: Have a look at function `dredge` in package MuMIn.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is however not clear which should be my global model to fill in in the dredge function. I understand that this function generates a set of models with combinations of the temrs in this global model. But this means that I need to specify a finite model. The goal however is to find the model -can be a of higher order than specified in the global model- that minimizes the AIC.

Comment: If you don't know the most complex model, how do you know when to stop adding terms?

Comment: There is no most complex model. I'll type the whole exercise to make it more clear: "Use the order selection idea to construct a test for additivity. The null hypothesis is that the model is additive, E(Y)=b0+b1x1+b2x2. The alternative hypothesis assumes a more complicated model. Constract a nested model sequency by adding one variable at time: x1x2, x1², x2², x2²*x1,x1²*x2, x1²*x2², x1³, etc. Use the order selection test to select the appropriate order and give the p-value." So the goal is that the AIC criterium will select the best model, regardless its degree.

Comment: So, when do you stop adding terms? When AIC doesn't improve for a step? The whole exercise seems fishy to me.

Comment: It seems fishy to me too. And yes, I suppose when AIC doesn't improve for a step :-)

Comment: You could start with one simple model, save the formula (`my.frml <- formula(your.model)`), and then you could use the function `update` in a loop to add more and more terms. For instance, `update(my.frml, .~. + new.var)` adds new.var to the existing formula and refits the model.

Answer (score 0):

The `addterm` function provided by MASS should get you close:

```
library(MASS)
null <- lm(null <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
alt <- addterm(null, ~. + x1*x2 + I(x1^2) + I(x2^2) + I(x1^2)*x2 + I(x2^2)*x1 + I(x1^2)*I(x2^2))
alt$AIC
```

Comment: missing a bracket `lm(null <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2))`